# Nesting vLookup inside multiple IFNA

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I've nested a vLookup inside IFNA to change the `#N/A` error to "Not on the list", this works fine.

I'm now failing to alter the `0` results to "On the list, but no data".

I'm not sure if this is even the correct approach, this is for business users so I don't want the sheet full of #N/As and 0's if I can avoid it.

`=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,V2:AB320,3,TRUE), "Not on list")`

I tried nesting an IFNA inside the IFNA but that didn't alter anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A2,V2:AB320,3,TRUE)=0,"On the list, but no data",VLOOKUP(A2,V2:AB320,3,TRUE)),"Not on list")
```

Comment: Pretty much @BigBen looking to add a check to see if it's a 0 and if it's a zero I need it to say "On the list, but no data".

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!